# Equivalent implementation of curl request using urllib2

Tags: python, curl, urllib2

I have a `curl` command:

```
curl -H 'XXX:1' -b headerinfo https:.....com/getinfo
```

However, I want to do the same thing using Python.
I tried the following:

```
with open('headerinfo', 'r') as headerfile:
    newData = headerfile.read()

req = urllib2.Request("https:....com/getinfo ", newData)
req.add_header('XXX', '1')
res2 = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

However, the above code does not work. Is there something I am missing that is preventing my code from working?

Comment: What errors are you seeing from the python code ?

Comment: I don't think it's python error.. I got "urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized".. probably because the headerinfo was not sent correctly.. not sure

Comment: "it doesn't work" is extremely vague. It might be good if you specify exactly how it doesn't work - error messages, log files, exceptions, etc...

Answer (score 0):

`-b` option is used to send cookies to a web server. If the value of `-b` is `name=value`, it'll be sent as cookie otherwise the value is used as file name of cookie data.

To send cookies you have to create an opener.

```
import cookielib, urllib2
cj = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar()
cj.load('headerinfo')
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders.append(('XXX','1'))
response = opener.open("http://example.com/")
```

Comment: I got an error  "cookielib.LoadError: 'headerinfo' does not look like a Netscape format cookies file"  what do I do?

Comment: try replacing `cookielib.MozillaCookieJar()` with `cookielib.FileCookieJar()`

Comment: or with `cookielib.LWPCookieJar()` which loads from and save cookies to disk in format compatible with the libwww-perl library’s Set-Cookie3 file format. Check what format the file is with linux `file` command. If it's sqlite3, you have to export it to Netscape format with [export-cookies](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/export-cookies/)

Comment: with FileCookieJar().. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "curl_json.py", line 26, in <module>
    cj.load('headerinfo')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/cookielib.py", line 1763, in load
    self._really_load(f, filename, ignore_discard, ignore_expires)
AttributeError: FileCookieJar instance has no attribute '_really_load'

Comment: I was wrong `cookielib.FileCookieJar()` is a base class which shouldn't be used.